# PHP syntactic sugar vs. Perl

Tags: php, perl

I am trying to orient myself in PHP, coming from Perl, [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29), C, and a couple of other languages.

Questions:

1. Are there PHP-isms to replace the following Perl syntax sugar?

   ```
   $y= $x || "I am undefined";  ## Default value
   ($x==1) or die "problem with $x";  ## Works under some circumstances
   $y= ($x1==1) ? 2 : ($x2==2) ? 3 : ($x3==3) ? 2 : 5;  ## Chaining needs () in PHP
   print "Val: $array[$x]";  ## Does not work with $_SESSION[...] in PHP
   ```

   Of course, I can write longer function/constructs that have the same functionality, but maybe there are standard PHP short ways to replace these fairly common useful constructs.
2. What syntactic sugar does PHP have that my other language experience does not suggest?

Comment: PHP is *unique/special* among programming languages in making the trinary conditional operator left associative.  Make your colons unhappy (`:(`) and close all the parens at the end of the statement.

Comment: @tjd Frowny-ternary statements. Heh. Nice trick.

Comment: why?  is there any advantage here why the php group is not changing it?  is any code using left association in a useful manner?

Comment: I doubt it; my guess is that this behaviour is not a result of conscious design choice and honestly it doesn't come as surprise when it comes to php.

Answer (score 4):

1.

You can think of `?:` as `||` in perl, but it is actually ternary/(trinary?) operator where second parameter is omitted and implies first one (`$x`).

```
$y= $x ?: "I am undefined"; # not before v5.3.x
```

You can't `($x==1) or return|break|continue;` so you have to use regular `if` condition (braces can be omitted for single statements)

```
if (!($x==1)) break;
```

As for chaining ternary, I'm afraid that things are not simple as you think if you want it to work like in perl

```
$y = ($x1==1 ? 2 :
     ($x2==2 ? 3 :
     ($x3==3 ? 2 : 5
))); // close as many times as there is rows above
```

You can use braces if your variable does not interpolate inside double quotes,

```
print "Val: {$array[$x]}";
```

2.

As for syntactic sugar you can use

```
$arg += array(
  "default" => 55,
);
```

like you would

```
%arg = ("default" => 55, %arg);
```

in perl in order to give default values for missing hash keys.

Comment: PHP7 has the null-coalesce operator `??`, which I'm already putting to good use - it's like `?:` but it doesn't trigger if `$x` is `0`, `false` or anything other than `null`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol this is good to know, and perl has `//` equivalent.